# How to read only one key to get value from Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get only value (address and phone) at `5A4WDqhepiOwy4fDKM9OzocHNdX2`!

This is my database in Firebase Database:

```
  "users" : {
    "5A4WDqhepiOwy4fDKM9OzocHNdX2" : {
      "address" : "123456",
      "displayname" : "han",
      "email" : "phamvanhan68@gmail.com",
      "id" : "5A4WDqhepiOwy4fDKM9OzocHNdX2",
      "phone" : "1234567890"
    },
    "iFFzXSnwMDTWXbxKIFmnVuw18Wf1" : {
      "address" : "han",
      "displayname" : "han",
      "email" : "111111@gmail.com",
      "id" : "iFFzXSnwMDTWXbxKIFmnVuw18Wf1",
      "phone" : "0123456789"
    }
  }
```

This is my code !

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
idUser = user.getUid();
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        DataSnapshot dataSnapshotTyperService =dataSnapshot.child("users");
        getInfor(dataSnapshotTyperService);
        Log.d("kiemtra12345", idUser+"");

    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

And

```
void getInfor (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            User uInfo = new User();
            uInfo.setDisplayname(ds.child(idUser).getValue(User.class).getDisplayname());
            uInfo.setPhone(ds.child(idUser).getValue(User.class).getPhone());
            uInfo.setAddress(ds.child(idUser).getValue(User.class).getAddress());

            Log.d("kiemtra123451", "showData: name: " + uInfo.getDisplayname());
            Log.d("kiemtra123452", "showData: email: " + uInfo.getEmail());
            Log.d("kiemtra123453", "showData: phone_num: " + uInfo.getPhone());


            ArrayList<String> array  = new ArrayList<>();
            array.add(uInfo.getDisplayname());
            array.add( uInfo.getEmail());
            array.add(uInfo.getPhone());
            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);
            lvtest.setAdapter(adapter);

            Log.d("kiemtraaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",lvtest+"");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you post your code through editing this question? Please show us what you tried to do.

Comment: I uploaded it again , you can see above !

Comment: Can you help me ? Plz .

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Your JSON contains `user` (singular), while your code uses `dataSnapshot.child("users")` (plural).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  
I uploaded it again , you can see it ! I'm had wrong in the fist time ! Sory !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
DatabaseReference myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("user/Harry");

myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        User myUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
        Log.d("FB", myUser.getAddress());
        Log.d("FB", myUser.getPhone());
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
});
```